# How to send multiple context in Outlet Context? react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

First of all, I use react-router-dom v6 in my project. As you know, it has the Outlet which provides to manage routes.
The example below works perfectly

This is the parent route. layout.js

```
    export default function Layout() {
            const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
        
    return (
    
    /* Header*/
    
    /* Content*/
    <Outlet context={[darkMode, setDarkMode]} />
    
    /* footer*/
                
    )
}
```

This is the child route. login.js

```
export default function Login() {
             const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useOutletContext();

    return (
/*Some Codes*/    
    )
}
```

When I want to send multiple props with context, it doesn't work.

Like this:

```
export default function Layout() {
                const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
            

const [color, setColor] = useState("#fff");
    
        return (
    
        /* Header*/
    
        /* Content*/
        <Outlet context={{ darkMode: [darkMode, setDarkMode], color: [color, setColor] }} />
    
        /* footer*/
    
        )
    }
    
    


export default function Login() {
                 const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useOutletContext();
    const [color, setColor] = useOutletContext();
    
        return (
    /*Some Codes*/    
        )
    }
```

How can I send multiple props with Outlet Context? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code example the `Outlet`'s context value is `[darkMode, setDarkMode]`, and the code is correctly using array destructuring assignment to access `darkMode` and `setDarkMode`.

```
<Outlet context={[darkMode, setDarkMode]} />
```

...

```
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useOutletContext();
```

Now in the second example the `Outlet` is providing a context value of a different shape, `{ darkMode: [darkMode, setDarkMode], color: [color, setColor] }`. It's instead now an object with `darkMode` and `color` properties. Outlet context consumers now must use ***object destructuring assignment*** to access the values.

```
<Outlet
  context={{
    darkMode: [darkMode, setDarkMode],
    color: [color, setColor],
  }}
/>
```

...

```
const { darkMode, color } = useOutletContext();
// darkmode -> [darkMode, setDarkMode]
// color    -> [color, setColor]
darkMode.darkMode
darkMode.setDarkMode
... etc...
```

You can combine the object destructuring with variable renaming and array destructuring assigment as well.

```
const {
  darkMode: [darkMode, setDarkMode],
  color: [color, setColor],
} = useOutletContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

i Think you are passing both color and setcolor thats wrong through props we can only pass only data that is in our color , so try only passing color not setColor and also if there is still issue then remove your array also

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).